# How to reference User model in views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have extended the Django User model as per the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Onboarding(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    onboarding_status = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=1, default=1)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Onboarding

def home(request):
    current_user = request.user
    u = User.objects.get(id=current_user.id)
    onboarding_status = u.onboarding.onboarding_status

    context = {
    }

    if onboarding_status == 1:
        return render(request, "onboarding/step_1.html", context)
    else:
        return render(request, "onboarding/step_2.html", context)
```

However, I get an error `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /onboarding/`. `User has no onboarding.`

How do I accurately reference the onboarding_status integer I have associated with the user from a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it is pointless to query User for the `request.user` ID. `request.user` is *already* a User: the value of `u` is exactly the same as the `current_user` value you started with.

Secondly, the error is telling you that this particular User has no related Onboarding instance. You need to create one, probably when you create the user.

Comment: Thanks, doesn't the model create the Onboarding instance because I assigned it a default value? It shows value=1 when I view it in the admin console.

Comment: @danihp Thanks, but I don't understand what the link is supposed to be showing?

Comment: The field `onboarding_status` in the Onboarding model has a default value, but you still have to actually create a related Onboarding instance for your user; there is no such thing as a default for that. I actually suspect that a custom user model, which inherits from AbstractUser and adds the `onboarding_status` field directly on that model, would be easier in your case: see that same docs page you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned `onboarding_status = u.onboarding.onboarding_status` but your `context = {}` is empty. Try `context={'onboarding_status': onboarding_status}`. And then in the template files, that is `step_1.html` or `step_2.html`, use `{{ onboarding_status }}` to call the variable.